# How long until my variable reaches zero?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to figure out how many seconds it takes for my value to reach zero.

```
`x` is a non-negative number.
`a` is a non-negative number.
`b` is a non-negative number.
`bMax` is a non-negative number.

Every second, `x` is reduced by `a`.

Every second, `x` is increased by `b`, up to the cumulative total of `bMax`.
```

---

```
So if `x = 10`, `a = 2`, `b = 1`, and `bMax = 5`:

After 0 Seconds, x == 10
(Starting Value)

After 1 Second, x == 9
(x = 10 - 2 + 1)

After 2 Seconds, x == 8
(x = 9 - 2 + 1)

After 3 Seconds, x == 7
(x = 8 - 2 + 1)

After 4 Seconds, x == 6
(x = 7 - 2 + 1)

After 5 Seconds, x == 5
(x = 6 - 2 + 1)
bMax was reached, so b will no longer be subtracted from x

After 6 Seconds, x == 3
(x = 5 - 2)

After 7 Seconds, x == 1
(x = 3 - 2)

After 7.5 Seconds, x == 0
(x = 3 - 2 * 0.5)
```

---

```
F(x, a, b, bMax) = Seconds
F(10, 2, 1, 5) = 7.5
```

I can figure out the formula if b == 0 or bMax == 0:

```
F(x, a, 0, 0) = x / a
```

But I cannot figure out how to include b in the equation.

If `a == b && b <= bMax`, then I believe the following formula works:

```
F(x, a, b, bMax) = x / (a - b)
```

But this does formula does not work otherwise.

Any ideas on how to create this formula?

Answer (score 2):

You need to handle the two components separately. The state of your system is $$F(t) = \begin{cases} x + (b-a)t \qquad \quad 0\leq t < \frac{bMax}{b} \\ x - at + bMax  \qquad t \geq \frac{bMax}{b} \end{cases}$$
So if it does not reach zero within the first interval, it will have a zero findable by the second equation.

So, either $\dfrac{x}{a-b} < \dfrac{bMax}{b}$, in which case $\dfrac{x}{a-b}$ is your time, or else it is $\dfrac{x+bMax}{a}$.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't quite understand it (yet), but I am testing it out.  Thanks!  (I may come back with a follow up question if I still need help understanding it after playing with it)

Answer (score 1):

The value is:
$$
y(t)=x-at+\text{min}\{bt,b_{max}\}
$$

it will reach zero at:
$$
t=\text{max}\{{x \over a-b},{b_{max} \over a-b} +{x+b_{max} \over a}\} 
$$

Comment: time is the unknown I am trying to solve for.  Sorry, I am new to asking questions here.  Can I rephrase the question somehow?

Comment: Check it now...

Comment: Thanks!  I am studying it now.